# how to fix regex to remove xml nottation before each elements?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have xml in string - format like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<User>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <User>
        <objectId>c33edcd9-5c13-4ceb-a81a-0a8f44b813ed</objectId>
    </User>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <User>
        <objectId>c33edcd9-5c13-4ceb-a81a-0a8f44b813ed</objectId>
    </User>
</User>
```

But each element has `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>` line before.

How to using regex remove this extra line, but to save nottation under all container like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<User>
    <User>
        <objectId>c33edcd9-5c13-4ceb-a81a-0a8f44b813ed</objectId>
    </User>
    <User>
        <objectId>c33edcd9-5c13-4ceb-a81a-0a8f44b813ed</objectId>
    </User>
</User>
```

I tried to use

```
public static String removeExtraMetadata(String xml, String tag){        
       return  xml.replaceAll("(?s)<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" 
                         standalone=\"yes\"?>.*?", "");
    }
public static String removeExtraMetadata(String xml, String tag){
return xml.replaceAll("(?s)<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>.*?" + tag, tag);
    }
```

but this ways not work for me..

Tried to way

```
 public static String removeExtraMetadata(String xml){
       return  xml.replaceAll("^\\s+<\\?xml\\s+version=\"1.0\".*\\n", "");
 }
```

but result still incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to match the line you want to remove from your xml,

```
^\s+<\?xml\s+version="1.0".*\n
```

Here, `^\s+` ensures the first line doesn't match which is desired to be retained in the file and rest lines starting with `<?xml version="1.0"` are removed as rest of them start with some space.

And replace it with empty string,

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YMUiYq/1)**

Check this Java code,

```
String s = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n" + "<User>\n"
        + "    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n" + "    <User>\n"
        + "        <objectId>c33edcd9-5c13-4ceb-a81a-0a8f44b813ed</objectId>\n" + "    </User>\n"
        + "    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n" + "    <User>\n"
        + "        <objectId>c33edcd9-5c13-4ceb-a81a-0a8f44b813ed</objectId>\n" + "    </User>\n"
        + "</User>";

System.out.println("Before: " + s);
System.out.println("After: " + s.replaceAll("\\s+<\\?xml\\s+version=\"1.0\".*", ""));
```

It prints this where it removes the lines you wanted to remove,

```
Before: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<User>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <User>
        <objectId>c33edcd9-5c13-4ceb-a81a-0a8f44b813ed</objectId>
    </User>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <User>
        <objectId>c33edcd9-5c13-4ceb-a81a-0a8f44b813ed</objectId>
    </User>
</User>
After: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<User>
    <User>
        <objectId>c33edcd9-5c13-4ceb-a81a-0a8f44b813ed</objectId>
    </User>
    <User>
        <objectId>c33edcd9-5c13-4ceb-a81a-0a8f44b813ed</objectId>
    </User>
</User>
```

Use the regex from my Java code samples, I have changed a bit to adjust for Java and string.

Comment: Can't to use it. Unit-test still failed(not removed meta annotations)

Comment: You answer is correct, and worked for me after removed ^ symbol in the begin of regex, thank you!

Comment: @Roberto: Yes I noticed as it was in String, I had to remove `^` to make it work in Java. Glad to know it worked :)

Comment: Another bug which is fixed in this answer is that OP forgot to escape the `?`. A literal `?` is represented in regexes by the string `\?`, hence `\\?` in a string literal. (And people always forget to escape `.`, but in this case, as in most cases, it doesn't really matter.)